# Install netgear wireless adapter with no internet

Tags: 12.04, wireless, netgear

Just installed ubuntu 12.04 LTS and I have a netgear wireless adapter A6200.

I have the disk but I need to work out a way to get the .INF files on to the machine. **I DO NOT have the ability to access the internet via Ethernet on the Ubunti machine.**

lsusb command - Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0846:9050 NetGear, Inc.

I have a laptop next to me with wireless access and a USB stick so I can download packages ans transfer across.

Please tell me how I can do this?

EDIT:

I have now installed some A6200 drivers using ndiswrapper and I can use modprobe ndiswrapper which loads the driver and I can see the wireless network, however it doesn't except the wireless key.

it's 100 percent the correct key but it just tries to connect for around 2 minutes and then the box pops back up asking for the authentication key again...

Comment: Do any of [these](http://askubuntu.com/search?q=A6200) help?

Comment: yes I now have a driver but ndiswrapper is not installed, how can I manually install that

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tell us what you did and where exactly you're stuck at.

Comment: I have just edited my main post. @terdon

Answer (score 0):

If you are having problems logging in, make sure that the encryption is correct. Go to the connection, go to security settings, and make sure that you chose the correct form of security encryption (WPA, WEP, etc.). Also, I know this may seem obvious but you might want to disconnect and reconnect to the network or restart the router.

See if that gets you anywhere.